# How to best handle an MMO for android

Tags: android, xml, json, request, mmo

I'm looking to create a simple MMO in android. I'm wondering what the best course of action would be in terms of sending/receiving data. There would be no rendering of graphics, it's all text-based. How would I send/receive data?

Would I just have a constant every second (It can afford to wait if there are a lot of old users, but new users would rack up a bunch of events) uploading the current status of one user and downloading the current status of the other users?

Would I use an API-like system with GET/POST requests in the form of JSON/XML? If I were to have a hundred users, each recording about 2000 characters a day, so 2000 bytes, plus some overhead, so we'll say 3000. That'd be 300,000 bytes, or 3mb of total data for a day's worth. It's not much, but when it's broken down and does a request constantly, it'll rack up, won't it? Hell, that might be a gross undervaluation of how much data will be sent.

Essentially, what I'm saying is, I don't know how to implement it. I've got the core game mechanics relatively fully coded, but it's not really fun unless it's compared with other players, ideally in real time.

Comment: Have you looked at GCM?

Comment: GCM? or Google Play Service

Comment: Nope, I've not even heard of it. Looks pretty promising. To give a good example of what it'd be like. It'd be similar to a somewhat busy IRC channel. And it'd work pretty much the same way (But obviously there wouldn't be more than one channel or server).